# KendoUI angular how to fix datepicker style

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

Can anyone please help me to figure out how I can fix this styling issue?
The datepicker is opening from grid filter.

column not aligning

[image: 1]

Here's the code.

```
<kendo-grid-column field="statusDateJson" title="Status Date" filter="date" format="{0:yyyy/MM/dd}">
  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
    <span>{{dataItem.statusDateJson | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</span>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

I need it to be aligned.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the `@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs` version (the latest at the moment of writing the answer is **v11.3.0**) as well as the installed Kendo Theme (**v6.0.2**).

> Note that these versions don't support Angular 12

More details on how to update the installed Kendo packages to their latest versions can be found here:

https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/installation/up-to-date/#toc-updating-to-latest-versions